# Inverse Derivative: Error/Intuition

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inverse-function

Problem is to find $[f^{-1}(4)]'$ given $f(x)=\frac{x^3+7}{2}$.

Way One: Switch $x$ and $y$ to find inverse function. So, $x=\frac{y^3+7}{2}$. Therefore, $\sqrt[3]{2x-7}=y$ (i.e. our inverse function). So, $f^{-1}(x)=(2x-7)^{\frac{1}{3}}$. So, $\frac{d}{dx}f^{-1}(x)=\frac{2}{3}(2x-7)^{-\frac{2}{3}}\implies \frac{d}{dx}f^{-1}(4)=\frac{2}{3}.$

Way Two: Switch $x$ and $y$ to find inverse function. So, $x=\frac{y^3+7}{2}\implies 2x=y^3+7\implies 2=3y^2\frac{dy}{dx}\implies \frac{1}{\frac{3}{2}y^2}=\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Now, this to me seems like the inverse function is $\frac{d}{dx}f^{-1}|_{x=3}=\frac{dy}{dx}|_{x=3}=\frac{1}{\frac{3}{2}y^2}$ when $x=3$ we know $y=f(3)$ which isn't our answer. So, what am I doing wrong here? Can someone explain what is incorrect with this reasoning? I feel like I am missing something when doing these problems.

Comment: In your case, $f^{-1}(4) =1$ so you should be plugging in $1$ not $3$

Comment: @PTrivedi Oh!! So, it's because $y=f^{-1}(x)$ is the inverse function and has nothing to do with what $y$ being the function $f(x)$. That makes sense.

Comment: Yes exactly! It's easy to get tripped up on that so I made it a point to use function names and not $y$ when solving these. See below

Comment: I suggest that you use $(f^{-1})' (4)$, it's better notation. When you write $[f^{-1}(4)]'$ it means that you are computing the derivative of an evaluation of a function, so the derivative of a constant which is $0$. Or, in the light of what @PTrivedi wrote, $\frac{d(f^{-1})}{dx}(4)$ which is even better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was tricky for me too so I started doing these problems the following way. You know that $f(f^{-1}(x)) = x$ so differentiating both sides gives you $$f'(f^{-1}(x)) \cdot \frac{d}{dx} f^{-1}(x) = 1 \implies \frac{d}{dx} f^{-1}(x) = \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x)) }.$$ Now $f^{-1}(4) = 1$ so $$\frac{d}{dx} f^{-1}(4) = \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(4)) } = \frac{1}{f'(1)} = \frac{1}{3(1)^2/2} = \frac{2}{3}.$$

Answer (score 1):

You already know that after switching variables
\begin{align*}
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{\frac{3}{2}y^2}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
Since we want to know $\left(f^{-1}(4)\right)^{\prime}$ we obtain again after switching variables from $x=\frac{y^3+7}{2}$ evaluated at $x=4$:

> \begin{align*}
> 4&=\frac{y^3+7}{2}\\
> 8&=y^3+7\\
> y&=1
> \end{align*}
> putting it into (1) we get
> \begin{align*}
> \left.\frac{dy}{dx}\right|_{y=1}&=\left.\frac{1}{\frac{3}{2}y^2}\right|_{y=1}
> \color{blue}{=\frac{2}{3}}
> \end{align*}
> in accordance with the first way.

*Note:* It might be easier to calculate way two without switching variables after all.